# Custom AppBarButton and AppBarToggleButton in Windows Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a custom an `AppBarButton` and an `AppBarToggleButton` in my Windows app. In the design view in Visual Studio I created a custom style that I applied to my button like so:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NewAppBarStyle" TargetType="AppBarToggleButton">
    (...)
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<AppBarToggleButton Icon="Stop" Label="Style" Style="{StaticResource NewAppBarStyle}" />
```

And in that view everything works fine. However, everytime I check the app in the phone, the result is not what I expected. Here are some pics:

[image: design view] [image: phone view]

I'm not sure why this happens and it would be a great help if someone could explain me why and how can I in fact create a custom `AppBarButton`.

Default style for the [AppBarButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn481531.aspx) and [AppBarToggleButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn481535.aspx).

You can find a project to test this here: http://1drv.ms/1OdhBwX

Comment: when button is selected, appbarbutton is going down. is that ur problem?

Comment: No, the left image is what I see in the Design View in VS and the result I want, and the right image is what I see in the phone after running the app. The style is not being applied.

Comment: did u try with find and replace option to replace the old image with new one in the entire solution? it might not be replaced with the new one.

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem. I'm not just trying to change the picture, that I can already do. What I'm trying to change is the whole data template. As you can see on the left picture I have different colors and a different template for the first secondary command (option w style), when I run the app, it completely ignores the style, as seen on the right. If you check the project you'll understand what I'm saying.